# Windows C++ bring launched child process to foreground

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, window

I am launching a child process via CreateProcess API. However, because it takes some time to start up and show its main window, its possible for the user to click elsewhere in the parent window while this is happening. The child window then goes to the background. How would I get it back into the foreground from the parent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SetWindowPos() for this in the past. It's kind of a swiss army knife, it can move and resize windows, as well as change their z-order position. You just want to change its z-order to HWND_TOP.

Answer (score 3):

You don't, the user decided that she was tired of waiting and wanted to work with a responsive program.  Review the fine print in SetForegroundWindow() for all the reasons that trying to find a workaround for this won't actually work.  Make sure she can get back to the program when it is initialized, a taskbar button is key.

Answer (score 0):

`SetActiveWindow()` also worked for me in the past, I recommend it.